# Oracle SQL query report on department users

Tags: sql, reporting, oracle12c

I have a table with multiple department teams which records number of users.

Department rows gets updated everyday, if there are any changes in users then it will add new entry or else only last_updated column gets updated. If departments gets closed then it will stop updating that record.

I think I have got most part of the report but somehow not able to have decent report in display.

Requirements

1. Department and number of users for 3 months (current and previous 2 months)

-- not sure if I can accept no. of months at runtime and query can determine required months to display.

2. List column name as Month-YYYY

Code:

```
create table departments   
(
    dept    varchar2(20),
    started date,
    users   number(6),
    row_updated date   
);

insert into departments 
values ('Developer', DATE'2019-09-25', 20, sysdate); 

insert into departments 
values ('Developer', DATE'2019-08-15', 15, sysdate); 

insert into departments 
values ('Developer', DATE'2019-03-03', 10, sysdate); 

insert into departments 
values ('Developer', DATE'2019-03-01', 5, sysdate);

insert into departments 
values ('Manager', DATE'2019-01-01', 3, sysdate);

insert into departments 
values ('HR', DATE'2019-08-15', 6, sysdate);

insert into departments 
values ('HR', DATE'2019-05-01', 3, sysdate);
```

Table:

```
 Dept        Started      Users  Row_Updated
 ----------  ------------ -----  -------------
 Developer   25-SEP-2019  20     25-SEP-2019
 Developer   15-AUG-2019  15     25-SEP-2019
 Developer   03-MAR-2019  10     25-SEP-2019
 Developer   01-MAR-2019  5      25-SEP-2019
 Manager     01-JAN-2019  3      25-SEP-2019
 HR       15-AUG-2019  5      25-SEP-2019
 HR          01-MAY-2019  3      25-SEP-2019
```

Report: (dept user count as of each month)

```
 DEPT       JUL-2019  AUG-2019  SEP-2019
 ---------  --------  --------  --------
 Developer  10        15        20
 Manager    3         3         3
 HR         3         5         5
```

Query for Sep:

```
 -- below query will display all departments status as of sept
 SELECT dept, users
 FROM
     (SELECT 
          dept, started, users,
          rank() over partition by dept
          order by started desc) seq
      FROM 
          departments
      WHERE 
          trun(started,'MM') <= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), -0)) d
WHERE 
    seq = 1
ORDER BY 
    1
```

I use above query 3 times with change in the WHERE clause, replacing 0 with 1 and 2 and select all result with another select and join.

Listed select 3 times doesn't look good and if tomorrow if we need 6 months then query needs to change again.

Comment: @marc_s, thanks for the format, looks much clean now.

Comment: And I'm assuming there should be a `(` after the  `rank() over` (and before the `partition by`) - right?

Comment: Yes, `rank() over` is correct, somehow missed while typing.  Thanks.

Comment: Challenges...  1. Is it possible to have single query and accept number of months needed of report and display them?  2. MON-YYYY as column name?

Comment: Congratulations on already figuring out the need for the analytical function `rank()` - the analytic stuff is mostly beyond me, but I *think* you may be able to use `pivot` or `unpivot` clause of the `select` statement to project over the 3 months?  You will probably need to update your where clause to be `seq <=3` and the `row_number` function to group the months?